# Edit and Continue broken on converted VS 2008-2010 project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xna, xna-4.0

I've looked through as many posts on broken EAC I can find but still can't find a solution.

I'm running VS2010 express on Win7 64bit now with XNA4.0 framework, I was running VS2008 express before on 32bit XP with XNA3.1 installed.

Did a conversion of the project, and EAC doesn't work. Gives me this error:
http://smars.se/misc/eac.jpg

It's the debug build, code is not optimized, x86 build, I've tried clearing all .user/.chachefile/.suo/bin/obj folders. When I create new projects EAC works. But I still can't get it working in my project.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than trying to fix this, might I suggest that it would be quicker and easier to simply recreate your project file(s)?

If you open them up in a text editor, you can simply copy out the `<ItemGroup>` that has all your source files. Then create a fresh project with the XNA 4.0 template. Edit the new project file and paste over the `<ItemGroup>` with your source files.

Obviously you will need to go through and reset things like the default namespace, output assembly name, and so on.

If you wanted to get even cleverer you could copy more sections of the project file over. Or you could even diff the the broken project file with a fresh one to figure out what might be causing the problem.